# Dynamic table name and variable name in query in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, dynamicquery

I am trying to make a query that I can run from Python with dynamic table name and date. In the process of this, I have tried the following query in SSMS, but it is producing an error message. How can I use variables for table name and a date, and get the query to work?

```
DECLARE @table_name VARCHAR(50)='table_name';
DECLARE @valid_to datetime = getdate();

EXEC('UPDATE '+ @table_name + '
SET valid_flag = 0, 
valid_to = '+ @valid_to +'
where valid_flag=1')
```

I get the following error message:

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 3
>   Incorrect syntax near '10'

Comment: You are missing a space after `UPDATE`.

Comment: Besides a lot of other flaws this comes quite obviously from here: `valid_to = '+ @valid_to +'`. Your `@valid_to` is declared as `datetime` and cannot be part of a string concatenation by `+`. But a `CAST` won't fix this (dateformat, quotes...) The correct solutions comes from Gordon: Use parameters and use `QUOTENAME()`! (or [meet bobby tables](http://bobby-tables.com/))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `sp_executesql` and parameters:

```
DECLARE @table_name VARCHAR(50) = 'table_name';
DECLARE @valid_to datetime = getdate();

DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(max) = N'
UPDATE '+ @table_name + N'
    SET valid_flag = 0, 
        valid_to = @valid_to
    WHERE valid_flag = 1
';

EXEC sp_executesql @sql, N'@valid_to datetime', @valid_to=@valid_to;
```

EDIT:

As recommended by Larnu a comment:

```
DECLARE @table_name sysname = 'table_name';
DECLARE @valid_to datetime = getdate();

DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(max) = N'
UPDATE '+ QUOTENAME(@table_name) + N'
    SET valid_flag = 0, 
        valid_to = @valid_to
    WHERE valid_flag = 1
';

EXEC sp_executesql @sql, N'@valid_to datetime', @valid_to=@valid_to;
```

Comment: I'd suggest `sysname` over `varchar(50)`, incase the OP does indeed have an object with a longer name. You should definitely make use of `QUOTENAME` though, SQL injection is not your friend. But at least the `WHERE` is parametrised.